# Windows Installer for chrome extension using NSIS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, windows-installer, crossrider

I have my chrome extension for my website, I want to make a windows installer for it. I used NSIS but it just copied the files and it does not appear in the extensions list. I have seen earlier a software , namely , lastpass which installs the extensions to different browsers. I have also used crossrider.com but my extension did not work. Can any one please tell me how to make a windows installer for my chrome extension

Comment: Windows-Installer doesn't refer to any installation technology on the windows platform.

Comment: Have you tried the methods in http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html?

Comment: No I did not, I used NSIS to install the folder but could not change the preferences file... can u please tell me how to change it

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Crossrider for your extension, you can create an installer by going to the **Settings** > **Windows Installer** page, selecting **Bundle Chrome** (and **Bundle Firefox** if required), saving the changes, and then clicking **Download Installer**.

Comment: actually when I try to upload my extension it does not upload and when I just past it manually and install it, it does  not work

Comment: OK, so the first step would be to get the extension working in Crossrider's framework, then you can try my answer :-) For the first step, as a Crossrider employee, I would suggest you email our support channel (support@crossrider.com) and we'll be happy to assist you in porting your extension.

Comment: OK i will send u a request there